# wildcards to display the content matching the particular month and year

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i want to display the content matching the particular format but i'm not unable to give this in the 
like please tell me how to give this statement in like

```
SELECT * FROM `attendance` WHERE `date` like 2014-10%
```

And the date in sql is in the format `2014-10-24`

Comment: is date is a pseudo string or datetime datatype ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your field 'date' is a datetime or date datatype, I would go with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM attendance
WHERE month(DATE) = 10
    AND year(DATE) = 2014;
```

Following is the sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb29/1

Comment: This works but the problem with using the date functions on the column is that it never use the index and for large data set the query will be very slow. The best approach is to use `between` start and end of the month so the index works properly for large data set.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Abhik. "conditional operators(<,>,=)" & "between" are the best way to work around dates, if the table have real huge records and indexed datetime field!